# HTML CSS JS Adding image slider in fullpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

geeks! I have a simple question for you. I'm practicing to school and creating one page website.

How to add gallery to this code? I want to add slide image gallery. For example to page 2 which scrolls horizontal by making simple two anchors on the left side and right side window. Want to change images by click on arrows, not by scrolling. Scrolling down should skip gallery and shows page 3 etc.

I was trying to put two divs into page section  with background images but it doesn't work for me. Images don't show up, even if I work with z-index. Do you have any solution to this?

```js
const $body = (window.opera) ? (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat" ? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body'),
      $section = $('section');

var numOfPages = $section.length - 1,
    curPage = 0,
    scrollLock = false;

function scrollPage() {
  
  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    if (scrollLock) return;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0)
      navigateUp();
    else
      navigateDown();
  });
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrollLock) return;
    if (e.which === 38)
      navigateUp();
    else if (e.which === 40)
      navigateDown();
  });
}

function pagination() {
  scrollLock = true;
  $body.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $section.eq(curPage).offset().top
  }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
    scrollLock = false;
  });
};

function navigateUp () {
  if (curPage === 0) return;
  curPage--;
  pagination();
};

function navigateDown() {
  if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
  curPage++;
  pagination();
};


$(function() {
  scrollPage();
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #2d314a;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #3c91b6;
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #6fc7bb;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #e59780;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
section h1 span {
  font: italic 300 1rem/1.5 calibri;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
section p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Full Page Scroll</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description...">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section>
  <h1><span>#1</span></h1>
  <p>1</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h1><span>#2</span></h1>
  <p>2</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h1><span>#3</span></h1>
  <p>3</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h1><span>#4</span></h1>
  <p>4</p>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and added slider related changes to page 2. Please check the below snippet:

```js
const $body = (window.opera) ? (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat" ? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body'),
      $section = $('section');

var numOfPages = $section.length - 1,
    curPage = 0,
    scrollLock = false;

function scrollPage() {
  
  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    if (scrollLock) return;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0)
      navigateUp();
    else
      navigateDown();
  });
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrollLock) return;
    if (e.which === 38)
      navigateUp();
    else if (e.which === 40)
      navigateDown();
  });
}

function pagination() {
  scrollLock = true;
  $body.stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $section.eq(curPage).offset().top
  }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
    scrollLock = false;
  });
};

function navigateUp () {
  if (curPage === 0) return;
  curPage--;
  pagination();
};

function navigateDown() {
  if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
  curPage++;
  pagination();
};


$(function() {
  scrollPage();
});

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #2d314a;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #3c91b6;
}
section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #6fc7bb;
}
section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #e59780;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5vh;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
section h1 span {
  font: italic 300 1rem/1.5 calibri;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
section p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/*slider*/

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev {
  left: 0
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Full Page Scroll</title>
  <meta name="description" content="website description...">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<section>
  <h1><span>#1</span></h1>
  <p>1</p>
</section>
<section>
  <!--h1><span>#2</span></h1>
  <p>2</p-->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/19/18/29/camel-4948299__340.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/21/19/27/sea-4955005__340.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/22/10/26/namibia-4956610__340.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
</section>
<section>
  <h1><span>#3</span></h1>
  <p>3</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h1><span>#4</span></h1>
  <p>4</p>
</section>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check on full page by expanding